# How to turn on XX:+PrintGCDetails and -Xloggc:gc.log in JMX console in Jboss EAP 5.1

Tags: garbage-collection, jmx, jboss5.x

How to turn on XX:+PrintGCDetails and -Xloggc:gc.log in JMX console in Jboss EAP 5.1? I need to turn on only for small period of time, so I need to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable PrintGCDetails at runtime, but loggc option can only be enabled at startup.  If you are using java 6 or above, another way to achieve something similar is by using the **jstat** utility. You can connect to a live pid and use the gcutil swtich to show stats, or redirect it to a file in your case.

On Windows, something like this:
**`<JDK>/bin/jstat -gcutil 11002 5000 > c:/gc.log`**

Assuming jboss process ID is 11002 you are telling it to output gc stats to gc.log every 5 seconds.

Here is a great article: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/